# UnicodeDecodeError in Python while reading UTF-8 sql file from English Wikipedia

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, wikipedia

**Update:** I have changed the encoding to

```
with open("../data/enwiki-20131202-pagelinks.sql", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

...and the program is now chewing through the file without complaint. Maybe the SQL dumps aren't UTF-8 and don't contain such literals, a false assumption on my part.

**Original:**

I'm trying to process one of Wikipedia's humongous data sets, namely the *pagelinks.sql* file.

Unfortunately I get the following error while reading the file:

```
(...)
File "c:\Program Files\Python 3.3\lib\codecs.py", line 301, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 5095: invalid start byte
```

My code is as follows:

```
import re

reg1 = re.compile(",0,")
ref_count = 0
with open("../data/enwiki-20131202-pagelinks.sql", encoding="utf8") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        matches = re.findall(reg1, line)
        ref_count += len(matches)

print ("found", ref_count, "references.")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excerpt from a comment under the "Unicode" heading here http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Dump_format may be helpful:

> "The dumps may contain non-Unicode (UTF8) characters in older text
>   revisions due to lenient charset validation in the earlier MediaWiki
>   releases..."

Ignoring for the moment the conflation of Unicode and UTF8 what you can do to avoid the error is pass the `errors` keyword argument to [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), e.g.:

```
filepath = "../data/enwiki-20131202-pagelinks.sql" 
with open(filepath, encoding="utf8", errors='replace') as infile:
    ...
```

That "causes a replacement marker (such as `?`) to be inserted where there is malformed data." http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

If you'd rather ignore the non-UTF8 characters you can use `errors='ignore'`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this wikipedia dumps issue. My script just terminated successfully using the ISO-8859-1 setting, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind.